# Magnific Popup Wordpress Audio Shortcode Keeps Playing after Close

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio, magnific-popup

I have created an inline popup for my custom Wordpress theme using Magnific Popup and the wp_audio_shortcode() function. It works beautifully, except that the audio keeps playing when I close the popup. (Embedded video stops exactly as expected, which is great!)

I read this post [magnific-popup, how to play an audio file when popup open and stop playing when closing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088518/magnific-popup-how-to-play-an-audio-file-when-popup-open-and-stop-playing-when) and it didn't quite address my problem; I get several javascript errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the HTML for the popup window that my function renders. I have removed extraneous things like web addresses and multi-line headlines.

THE LINK PEOPLE CLICK:

```
<a href="#popup-3" data-audio="audio-3" data-effect="popup-with-zoom-anim" class="open-popup-link popup-with-zoom-anim has_thumb" style="background-image:url('graphic.jpg') "><span class="pop-up-wrapper"><h2 class="homecard-title">Link Text</h2></span></a>
```

THE POPUP THAT APPEARS:

```
<div id="popup-3" class="pop-up-post zoom-anim-dialog">
     <div class="pop-up-left"><img src="graphic.jpg" class="pop-up-back-image"></div>
     <div class="pop-up-right">
          <h2 class="homecard-title">Headline Here<br><span class="play-wrapper" id="audio-3"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->
<audio class="audio-3" id="audio-104-1" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls="controls"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://vivenne:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Vivienne-Leheny-Hot-Winter-NIghts-Lucas-Mom.mp3?_=1"><a href="http://vivenne:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Vivienne-Leheny-Hot-Winter-NIghts-Lucas-Mom.mp3">http://vivenne:8888/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Vivienne-Leheny-Hot-Winter-NIghts-Lucas-Mom.mp3</a></audio></span></h2>
     </div>

     <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>

</div>
```

The jquery for Magnific (taken directly from the website):

```
        $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',

            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,

            overflowY: 'auto',

            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,

            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',

        });
```

When the close button is clicked, I would like the audio to STOP playing, but it continues in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Well folks, I solved it. I abandoned the `wp_audio_shortcode()`, which made it easier to assign an ID to the `<audio>` element.

I am happy to provide all of the code, but I think it's confusing out-of-context. Here are the important tidbits…

The magnificPopup container gets a `data-ref` attribute that matches the audio player's ID contained within it. (I did this with a simple `$count` variable because there are several popups on the page.)

The important part for the magnificPopup jQuery is this:

```
callbacks: {
   close: function(){
      var magnificPopupVar = $.magnificPopup.instance,
      magnificPopupSrc = magnificPopupVar.currItem.src,
      magnificPopupRef = $(magnificPopupSrc).attr('data-ref'),
      audioplayer = document.getElementById('audio-popup-'+magnificPopupRef);
      audioplayer.pause();
   }
}
```

In context:

```
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',

    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,

    overflowY: 'auto',

    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,

    modal:false,

    midClick: true,
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',

    callbacks: {
        close: function(){
            var magnificPopupVar = $.magnificPopup.instance,
            magnificPopupSrc = magnificPopupVar.currItem.src,
            magnificPopupRef = $(magnificPopupSrc).attr('data-ref'),
            audioplayer = document.getElementById('audio-popup-'+magnificPopupRef);
            audioplayer.pause();
      }
   }
});
```

I hope that's helpful to someone else trying to sort this out!